# Using JQuery or JavaScript add one variable from cookies to Server Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

I added to cookie one variable using JQuery

```
    var url = 'smtp.example.com'; 
    $.cookie = 'domainName =' + url + '; domain=.example.com; path=/;';
```

After that is made a request to the server, and in Page_Load I receive in `Request.Cookies.AllKeys` only one its `"ASP.NET_SessionId"`,
`domainName` doesn't exist !!!

How add this variable `domainName` in a server request in ASP.NET WebProject when I change subdomain?

I need to use this variable for my all subdomains...

Maybe I need to use ajax request for set on server this cookie's variable?

Please any proposal to solve,...

Thanks in advance!